# pass variable from ng-grid Angulars.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm tring to to use a variable from a ng-grid table in another controller,

A part of my ng-grid is defined like this:

```
  app.controller('ng-grid-controller'){
        ....
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data:MyData,
        columnDefs: [
                    {field:'_id'},{name:'name',cellTemplate: 'templates/show.html'}]
    };
    $scope.getDetail = function(_id){

              alert(_id);
              var test=_id;
              console.log(test);
              return test;
    };
 }
```

I'm able to show the displayed value in my template `show.html` like this:

```
<div ng-style="{'cursor': row.cursor}" ng-click="getDetail(row.getProperty('_id'));" data >

</div>
```

But my question is how I can access this value inside another controller,I need to pass for example to pass this value as parameter for another template:

In my route I have something like that:

```
  when('/show/:thatValue', {// Here I want that value I display=thatValue
    templateUrl: 'templates/displayvalue.html',
    controller: 'ShowController'
  }).
```

And in my controller:

```
   app.controller('ShowController', function($scope) {

        $scope.value='the value I display';//Something like this

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to share data between controllers it's best to use a service then you can inject that value into your respective controllers.  For example:

```
app.factory('SomeService', [ '$log', function($log) {
   return {
      variable: null,
      getVariable: function() {
         return this.variable;
      },
      setVariable: function(value) {
         this.variable = value;
      }
   };
}]);
```

Then to use this in your Controller:

```
app.controller("MyController", [ '$scope', 'SomeService', function($scope, SomeService) {
    $scope.someMethod = function() {
       $scope.variable = SomeService.getVariable();
    };

    $scope.setSomeService = function(value) {
       SomeService.setVariable( value );
    }
}];
```